# Kotlin Spring Error when converting Java Component

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, components

I am trying to convert some Java Spring components into Kotlin, and I tried using the Intellij *Convert to Kotlin* feature.

The code converted in Kotlin is just fine, no errors, I checked the logic and there is no issue there.

The problem is that any kind of @Component I am trying to convert, it gives me a confusing error.

The error:

```
e: java.io.IOException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0
```

The Kotlin Component:

```
@Component
class Component {
    @Autowired
    private val service: Service? = null
    // Service class also in Kotlin, works just fine

    // ...
}
```

Java code:

```
@Component
public class Component {
    @Autowired
    private Service service;
    // Service class in Kotlin, works just fine

    // ...
}
```

I have also tried with having the component as an `open class`, but the same error came up.

Comment: Can you post more of the stack trace?  (I think the usual way of defining `@Autowired` properties is as non-nullable `lateinit var`, as you can then use them without any null check.  But I doubt that's the cause here.)

Comment: @gidds unfortunately that's the only message Intellij shows me. I don't get any other details